# Conditional Expected value of Binomial Distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

The expected value of a binomial distribution, $B(k, n, p)$ is $np$.

How do I go about calculating the conditional expectation, given that $k>0$, $E(B(k, n, p) | k>0)$?

I assume the answer is very simple but I do not know where to start.

**ATTEMPT AT A SOLUTION**

The expected value of a binomial distribution is given by:

$\mathrm{E}(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) p^{k} q^{n-k}$

I would assume that, in order to get $k>0$, one would simply start the sum from $k=1$. However, this term in the sum is already zero; and is part of the derivation for the expected value of the mean in any case.

I am aware of a relationship:

$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{E}(X \mid A) &=\sum_{x} x P(X=x \mid A) \\
&=\sum_{x} x \frac{P(\{X=x\} \cap A)}{P(A)}
\end{aligned}$

Yet I am not sure how it applies to my problem.

Comment: Well, if nothing else, you have an explicit form for the distribution, so you can just do the sum explicitly (at least if $k$ isn't too big).  And working that computation just might suggest a way to do it in general.

Comment: Unfortunately, calculating it is not the problem: I need the analytical solution to calculate a different quantity.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.  Working examples is by far the best way to get a sense of the problem, and you will certainly need a lot of examples in order to test whatever closed form you find.  (And, as i tried to hint before, working a few examples should tell you how to easily produce a general formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability for $k\gt 0$ is $1-q^n$ so $E(X|k\gt 0)=\frac{np}{1-q^n}$.

Comment: Could you give me a short explanation as to your reasoning? I have checked it is correct with simulation, but I do not understand the process behind how this is derived. I understand what you have done here is divide the expected value by the binomial probability of k>0, but where does this arise from?

Comment: Direct analysis. The numerator (as you noted) is the same as the sum for $E(X)$ with the $k=0$ term omitted.  The denominator is similarly the total probability with the $k=0$ term omitted.  This comes from the basic definition of conditional probability.

Comment: I see! Much easier than I thought - thank you very much for educating me here!